# How to call popup based on a condition in richfaces?

Tags: jsf, popup, richfaces

I am trying to understand popup menu in richfaces. I am trying to do the following: I have a textbox and a button. I write some text into the textbox, and if the value of the text written is "popup", i want to call the popup menu. Here is the code:

```
 <h:form>
        <h:inputText value="#{popupCall.text}"></h:inputText>
        <a4j:commandButton action="#{popupCall.showpopup()}" onclick="if (#{popupCall.showpopup()}) #{rich:component('popup')}.show();">
        </a4j:commandButton>

    </h:form>

    <rich:popupPanel id="popup" modal="false" autosized="true" resizeable="false">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Popup panel" />
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="controls">
            <h:outputLink value="#" onclick="#{rich:component('popup')}.hide();
                return false;">
                X
            </h:outputLink>
        </f:facet>

    </rich:popupPanel>
```

and the bean:

```
@ManagedBean (name="popupCall")
@VievScoped
public class PopupCall {

private String text;

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}
public PopupCall() {
}

public void checkText(){
    if(text.equals("popup")){
        //CALL POPUP MENU
    }
}

public boolean showpopup(){
    if(text!=null && text.equals("popup"))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

}
```

If i don't put "if(#{popupCall.showpopup()})" inside the onclick method it always calls when button is pressed but now even though the showpopup()method returns true no popup is shown. Also, inside the showpopup() method, if i just write return true, the if statement inside onclick works but now it does not.
Can anyone help me with this? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conditional invocation of rich:popup panel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957560/conditional-invocation-of-richpopup-panel)

Comment: The answer is in the link. Let me know if you don't understand it.

Comment: @Andy thanks i am trying it, but i think there is a problem with the "if" inside onclick method. Edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your case you want to use `oncomplete` instead of `onclick` since you want to show `<rich:popupPanel>` after executing some business logic. When I changed

```
onclick="if (#{popupCall.showpopup()}) #{rich:component('popup')}.show();"
```

to

```
oncomplete="if (#{popupCall.showpopup()}) #{rich:component('popup')}.show();"
```

The pop up showed up. Also be careful with

```
action="#{popupCall.showpopup()}"
```

Remember that `action` needs `String` (or `null`) for navigation but 
`showpopup()` is returning a `boolean` so you might want to fix that.

I found these links to be helpful check them out (for the first link, I liked the one with the highest vote).

[Primefaces onclick and onsuccess differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402264/primefaces-onclick-and-onsuccess-differences)

[EL expression inside p:commandButton onclick does not update/re-render on ajax request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822484/el-expression-inside-pcommandbutton-onclick-does-not-update-re-render-on-ajax-r)

Comment: @iceface Let me know if this didn't work. I was using Netbeans and I had some trouble along the way. In particular, check the js error console for any error messages if the panel doesn't pop up.

Comment: yeah i had figured out how to do it i just saw your answer. I did the same thing thanks

Comment: Great. Glad you solved it. Thanks for accepting my answer. I appreciate it.

Comment: how can we add if (#{popupCall.showpopup()}) #{rich:component('popup')}.show();
else statement with this